# I want to write trigger to automatically upload files in bulk on Account object file related list. Please help

Tags: apex, trigger, contentdocument

trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert)
{
//SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion where Id=:trigger.new[0].Id;

```
    ContentDocumentLink docLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    docLink.ContentDocumentId= trigger.new[0].ContentDocumentId;
    Account acc= [SELECT Id from Account where Customer_ID__c=:trigger.new[0].Title];
    docLink.linkedEntityId = acc.Id;
    docLink.shareType = 'V';
    Insert docLink;
```

}

Comment: This site isn't a free coding service. You need to [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far, and point to a specific and narrow thing that you're having trouble on. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be where you should start.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the **ContentDocumentLink** object, which is how Salesforce handles File sharing. These records represent individual relationships between a ContentDocument record (ie- File), and the entities it's related to (a User, File Library, Record, etc).

You will want to create a CDL record that uses the AccountId as the LinkedEntityId, and then pull the ContentDocumentId from whereever it's stored (sounds like it may be your Customer_ID field, but unclear).

Once those CDL records are created that's what drives the Files listed in that related list on the Account record, and will also be displayed anywhere else it's linked to. This is how the same File can be shared across several different locations, rather than each of those related records hosting their own cloned version of the file.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm